# How to store user entered credentials in CLI application?

Tags: desktop

I am working on a CLI application which gets an API key from the user and use it to authenticate to a cloud application. Once the user authenticated, I want to store the API key somewhere securely so that user don't need to enter it every time.

How to accomplish this requirement?

Comment: Can you give some more context? What OS are you on? What threats do you want to protect against?

Comment: Yeah basically what do you want to protect from. The common way to protect a secret is to encrypt it, with a secret key, but then you need the secret key to decrypt it, which seemingly you don't want. .NET offer a SecureString  (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring) mechanism which may do what you want, but you need to tell us more to be helped.

Comment: I am developing on mac os using nodeJs. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43526491/how-can-i-store-passwords-securely-in-operating-systems-default-key-store